# Убрать из предложения гласные

Tags: java

Кто может написать код который убирает из предложения гласные к примеру у нас есть предложение 
hi my name is Nick а нужно получить h m nm s Nck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out.println("hi my name is Nick".replaceAll("[aeiouyAEIOUY]", ""));`

Жалко что-ли? :)